# Firebase Cloud Messaging where to find PUBLIC VAPID KEY

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm implementing Push Notification for Web App via Firebase and follow this guidelines from Google

https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/tree/master/messaging

On `index.html` I see this code

```
    // [START get_messaging_object]
    // Retrieve Firebase Messaging object.
    const messaging = firebase.messaging();
    // [END get_messaging_object]

    // [START set_public_vapid_key]
    // Add the public key generated from the console here.
    messaging.usePublicVapidKey('<YOUR_PUBLIC_VAPID_KEY_HERE>');
    // [END set_public_vapid_key]
```

My question is "What is Vapid Key ? and Where I can find this key ?"

Answer (score 139, accepted):

Based on https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client

Vapid Key is "Voluntary Application Server Identification". We can find it in:

1. Open the [Cloud Messaging](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/settings/cloudmessaging/) tab of the Firebase console **Settings** pane and scroll to the **Web configuration** section.
2. In the **Web Push certificates** tab, click **Generate Key Pair**. The console displays a notice that the key pair was generated, and displays the public key string and date added.

Or look at steps by steps images below

1. Open Project settings

[image]

2. Choose **Cloud Messaging**, scroll down to **Web configuration**. In **Web Push certificates** you can find Vapid key ( If it doesn't exists, click **Generate Key Pair** to create )

[image]

[image]

Comment: thank you, I use it for `flutter_messaging`, and ok.

Comment: Tysm   i took the private key by mistake on the new UI though hahaha my mistakeee 