# Firebase token not generated in flutter web

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-web

Error:

> [firebase_messaging/token-subscribe-failed] Messaging: A problem occurred while subscribing the user to FCM: Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project. .
>
> at Object.createErrorWithStack (http://localhost:2277/dart_sdk.js:5080:12)
> at Function._throw (http://localhost:2277/dart_sdk.js:20337:18)
> at Function.throwWithStackTrace (http://localhost:2277/dart_sdk.js:20334:18)
> at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:2277/dart_sdk.js:40851:18)
> at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:2277/dart_sdk.js:40708:13)
> at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:2277/dart_sdk.js:40714:13)
> at http://localhost:2277/dart_sdk.js:36191:9

Comment: Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential.

Answer (score 1):

You need to generate a Vapid Key in the Firebase Settings | Cloud Messaging tab.

Please check the following answer on how to do that.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54996207/10086962